# Rails - multiple relationships between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have an existing database migration in my app that contains the following contents:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Each user can vote once either `like` or `dislike` for a course, so I created a join table in `db/migrate`:

```
class CreateUsersCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        create_table :users_courses do |t|
        t.integer :course_id, null: false
        t.integer :user_id, null: false
    end
end
```

Now I am not sure how to add new relationship in `User` and `Course` models that does not make it overlapped with the One-Many relationship.

Comment: Can each `Course` only belong to one `User`?

Comment: Yes because the case here is `User` creates `Course`. Now I want to do `User` votes `Course`, don't know how to add new relationships.

Comment: Can't you have the like/unlike then just as a column on your `Course` model then? It might seem unorthodox, but it's the simplest solution if `Course` ever only belongs to one `User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget that the associations between classes ought to describe the nature of the association. In this case there are multiple possible associations: a user can create a course, they can vote for a course, and they might study a course. Simple Rails naming conventions for the associations are not going to help you make sense of that.

If a course is created by a single user, then the relationship ought to be that the `course :belongs_to :creating_user`, and the `user has_many :created_courses`. You would add a `user_id` column to the courses table for this.

To allow voting by users on courses, you would use a join table between them. However, your association should describe the nature of the association, so calling the join table `user_course_votes` would make sense. Then you can have an association on the user of `has_many :user_course_votes`, and `has_many :course_votes, :through :user_course_votes` -- and appropriate associations on the course also.

The only thing you need to do to be able to name your associations whatever you like is to name the class or source in the association definition.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_courses, class_name: "Course"
  has_many :user_course_votes
  has_many :course_votes, through: :user_course_votes, source: course
end
```

This methodology allows you to add other associations between user and course, and assign meaningful names to them that will make your code easier to write and to understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Now you will want to add `User has_many :courses, through :user_courses` to User.
2. Create a new migration to add a boolean attribute on User to represent your like/dislike.
3. Course probably has many users.  It would make sense to want to see all of the users of a course.

Comment: The existing tables is based on my scenario that `User` creates `Course` so 1 `User` can create many courses, but 1 `Course` only belongs to 1 `User`.Now I want to add relationships to those `models` to allow `User` votes for `Course`. So I create `Users_Courses` table, which can be considered as `Votes` table containing `user_id` and `course_id`. Then I add to User: `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, through :users_courses, class :course` but it does not work

Comment: Ok that is a reasonable use case for Course belonging to a user.  It just sounded funny on the surface.  I will edit.